# How to query only specific id's in a custom source plugin

Tags: 8, migrations

I have 40/1040 source product_id's I need to ignore in one migration, so that I can put them in their own separate migration. I can exclude and include them in the yaml files, but it's a bit ugly and I would rather do so in the custom source plugin because doing this in the yaml is not performant as they are all queried in both.

I can exclude the 40 from their own yaml this way:

```
process:
  variation_id:
    -
      plugin: skip_on_value
      source: product_id
      method: row
      value:
        - 1
        - 2
        - all the way to 40
```

I can include only the 40 in another yaml this way:

```
process:
  variation_id:
    -
      plugin: skip_on_value
      not_equals: true
      source: product_id
      method: row
      value:
        - 1
        - 2
        - all the way to 40
```

But I would rather set a string of `product_id`'s to include/exclude (I'm guessing in the `public function query()`??) because when I run the smaller migration (the 40) there is no need to query and ignore the other 1000 variations.

I created a copy of the source plugin so that I could use a distinct plugin for each of the 2 migrations. Here is the plugin that I am currently using for both:

```
use CommerceGuys\Intl\Currency\CurrencyRepository;
use Drupal\migrate\Row;
use Drupal\migrate_drupal\Plugin\migrate\source\d7\FieldableEntity;

/**
 * Gets Commerce 1 commerce_product data from database.
 *
 * @MigrateSource(
 *   id = "commerce1_product_bundle",
 *   source_module = "commerce_product"
 * )
 */
class CommerceProduct extends FieldableEntity {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function fields() {
    return [
      'product_id' => t('Product variation ID'),
      'sku' => t('SKU'),
      'title' => t('Title'),
      'type' => t('Type'),
      'language' => t('Language'),
      'status' => t('Status'),
      'created' => t('Created'),
      'changed' => t('Changes'),
      'data' => t('Data'),
      'commerce_price' => t('Price with amount, currency_code and fraction_digits'),
    ];
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getIds() {
    $ids['product_id']['type'] = 'integer';
    $ids['product_id']['alias'] = 'p';
    return $ids;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function query() {
    $query = $this->select('commerce_product', 'p')->fields('p');
    if (isset($this->configuration['product_variation_type'])) {
      $query->condition('p.type', $this->configuration['product_variation_type']);
    }
    return $query;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function prepareRow(Row $row) {
    $product_id = $row->getSourceProperty('product_id');
    $revision_id = $row->getSourceProperty('revision_id');
    foreach (array_keys($this->getFields('commerce_product', $row->getSourceProperty('type'))) as $field) {
      $row->setSourceProperty($field, $this->getFieldValues('commerce_product', $field, $product_id, $revision_id));
    }
```

So I'm asking how to exclude an array of 40 product_id's in one plugin, and then only include an array of 40 product_id's in the other plugin.

Should I do this in the `public function getIds()`, the `public function query()`, or the `public function prepareRow(Row $row)`?

My guess would be in the `public function query()` But I would like to know the best way, and why.

Comment: When [drupal#3069776: SQL source plugins: allow defining conditions in migration yml](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3069776) lands, it should be possible to do this from the Yaml configuration alone. As of Feb 2021 the issue is still WIP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was quite easy by adding a `$query->condition()` to `public function query()` using `IN` and `NOT IN` [in dynamic queries](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/database-api/dynamic-queries/conditions#s-using-in-not-in)

This worked to exclude certain id's:

```
$products = [1, 2, 3,];
$query->condition('product_id', $products, 'NOT IN');
```

This worked to include only certain id's:

```
$products = [1, 2, 3,];
$query->condition('product_id', $products, 'IN');
```

I was then able to clean up the yamls, and only query the stuff I wanted.